# Controlling Morris Donut Chart dimesnions i.e. Height & width

Tags: javascript, html, css, morris.js

I'm using Morris chart to draw donut chart. 
but I want to control its height. Donut chart always has fixed size. It doesn't respect the dimensions of div.when I reduce the height of div Donut chart overflows.

```
    <html>
      <head>
         #donutChart{
             height:200px;
         }
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="donutChart"></div>
      </body>
    <script>
    var donutData = [{label:"A", count:100},
                 {label:"B", count:200},
                 {label:"C", count:300}
                ]
    var color: [ "red", "green", "blue"]
    drawDonutChart( divId, donutData, colors ){
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < donutData.length ; i++){
            var item = donutData[i];
            total += item.value
        } 
        Morris.Donut({
            element: divId,
            data: donutData,
            colors: colors,
            formatter: function(x) {
                return Math.round( (x*100)/total ) +"% ("+ x +")" ;
            }
        });
    }
   </script>
   <html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What s expected result?

Comment: I want to specify the size of div & donut chart should fill that div only it should not cross the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in morris.js `Donut.prototype.redraw = function()` Please check these lines:

```
  cx = this.el.width() / 2;
  cy = this.el.height() / 2;
```

Don't forget to set the parent dom element dimensions, too.
Hope this helps!